# Cooler Master MasterPulse Pro 7.1 USB Microphone too quiet Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, microphone, audio-recording

So I just got this gaming headset for my linux machine and the mic is very quiet.  Mic volume is on max and can be heard in game if other game sound is not very loud, but it's very quiet.

The gain option in the audio panel is greyed out.

Any ideas?  Short of changing a driver, I've tried everything I can think of.

Thanks.

```
pacmd list-sources                   
2 source(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.usb-Cool_Master_Co._Ltd_MasterPulse_Pro_7.1ch_with_Bass_FX-00.analog-stereo.monitor>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY                                                                                                                                        
        state: IDLE                                                                                                                                                                          
        suspend cause:                                                                                                                                                                       
        priority: 1040                                                                                                                                                                       
        volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB                                                                                                    
                balance 0.00                                                                                                                                                                 
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB                                                                                                                                                  
        volume steps: 65537                                                                                                                                                                  
        muted: no
        current latency: 0.00 ms
        max rewind: 375 KiB
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 2000.00 ms; range is 66.00 .. 2000.00 ms
        monitor_of: 0
        card: 0 <alsa_card.usb-Cool_Master_Co._Ltd_MasterPulse_Pro_7.1ch_with_Bass_FX-00>
        module: 6
        properties:
                device.description = "Monitor of MasterPulse Pro 7.1ch with Bass FX  Analog Stereo"
                device.class = "monitor"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "MasterPulse Pro 7.1ch with Bass"
                alsa.long_card_name = "Cool Master Co.,Ltd MasterPulse Pro 7.1ch with Bass at usb-0000:03:00.0-4, full"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:03:00.0-usb-0:4:1.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/sound/card1"
                udev.id = "usb-Cool_Master_Co._Ltd_MasterPulse_Pro_7.1ch_with_Bass_FX-00"
                device.bus = "usb"
                device.vendor.id = "0c76"
                device.vendor.name = "JMTek, LLC."
                device.product.id = "1552"
                device.product.name = "MasterPulse Pro 7.1ch with Bass FX "
                device.serial = "Cool_Master_Co._Ltd_MasterPulse_Pro_7.1ch_with_Bass_FX"
                device.string = "1"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
  * index: 1
        name: <alsa_input.usb-Cool_Master_Co._Ltd_MasterPulse_Pro_7.1ch_with_Bass_FX-00.analog-mono>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE 
        priority: 9049
        volume: mono: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 19944 /  30% / -31.00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0.00 ms
        max rewind: 0 KiB
        sample spec: s16le 1ch 48000Hz
        channel map: mono
                     Mono
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
        card: 0 <alsa_card.usb-Cool_Master_Co._Ltd_MasterPulse_Pro_7.1ch_with_Bass_FX-00>
        module: 6
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "USB Audio"
                alsa.id = "USB Audio"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "MasterPulse Pro 7.1ch with Bass"
                alsa.long_card_name = "Cool Master Co.,Ltd MasterPulse Pro 7.1ch with Bass at usb-0000:03:00.0-4, full"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:03:00.0-usb-0:4:1.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/sound/card1"
                udev.id = "usb-Cool_Master_Co._Ltd_MasterPulse_Pro_7.1ch_with_Bass_FX-00"
                device.bus = "usb"
                device.vendor.id = "0c76"
                device.vendor.name = "JMTek, LLC."
                device.product.id = "1552"
                device.product.name = "MasterPulse Pro 7.1ch with Bass FX "
                device.serial = "Cool_Master_Co._Ltd_MasterPulse_Pro_7.1ch_with_Bass_FX"
                device.string = "hw:1"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "192000"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "96000"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-mono"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Mono"
                device.description = "MasterPulse Pro 7.1ch with Bass FX  Analog Mono"
                alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
                alsa.components = "USB0c76:1552"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
        ports:
                analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        active port: <analog-input-mic>
```

Answer (score 1):

check ALSA recording settings in - alsamixer - c 0 --view capture

may be additional control to boost mic level by 10dB or 20dB in addition to usual level control

recommend turning down level before increasing boost!

command `amixer -c 0` will display same ALSA information in text format.
amixer commands using 'set' option can be used to change any settings

Increasing microphone ALSA level should also show in Pulseaudio